# Manipulation of dataset records in delphi like datatable in .NET

Tags: delphi, informix

I have a scenario where I have to get some number of records based on query then manipulate each records and display the message for each record. In .NET I can accomplish this using datatable and using For Each in "dt.Rows". But How can I accomplish this in delphi. My backend db is informix and I am using Delphi 2010 version. I have to use BDE. It will better If I can get some sample code.

Comment: My heart stops beating every time I read the sentence "I have to use BDE". As you may BDE is old and obsolete technology and should be banned from new Delphi versions... FYI More recent Delphi versions have a native driver for Informix.

Comment: Thats is very helpful I will remember this. But the scenerio is such that I have to :(

Comment: Using BDE is the equivalent to using Windows 98. It's just not done.

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to process records in a Delphi dataset (of any type) is with code like this

```
DataSet.First;
while not DataSet.eof do begin
   // process the current record here
   DataSet.Next;
end;
```

Before that loop, you should use TDataSet.GetBookMark to record where the dataset cursor previously was, and call DisableControls.

Surround the loop with a try.. finally block.  In the "finally" section use GotoBookmark to restore the cursor position, then call FreeBookmark and lastly, EnableControls.

You will need to look all these up in the OLH.

Comment: @AkshayJamwal Yes there was, I just formatted it to stand out.

Answer (score 1):

The code below iterates over a dataset:

```
myDataset.Open; // here we open the dataset and load the records
while not myDataset.Eof do begin
  // here you put the code to work over the current record

  myDataset.Next;
end; // while not the last record
```

This is the standard and safer way to iterate along all the records contained in the dataset, from the first to the last record. If you need to go backwards, then the code is:

```
myDataset.Open; // here we open the dataset and load the records
myDataset.Last; // here we move to the last record
while not myDataset.Bof do begin
  // here you put the code to work over the current record

  myDataset.Prior;
end; // while not the first record
```

Comment: The other answer states about using `EnableControls` and `DisableControls`. It´s indeed a good advice that I overlooked in order to make the code simpler. Take a look an the help for details on those two methods.

Comment: Can you tell me How can use your code with TClientDataSet I have TDataSource and TQuery Components with me?

Comment: How to get the data in the TCLientDataSet. or is there any other dataset I can use?

Comment: @AkshayJamwal: this code works with any dataset, `TQuery` included. In order to use `TClientDataset` I recomend that you expend some time studing it. There is much more information you need to learn than a comment can carry. However, I asure you that those hours will be rewarded by better code, better application and less headacked.

Comment: @AkshayJamwal Your question about how to get data into a client dataset is a separate question and shouldn't be asked in the comments to an answer. You should make it a separate question.